# InDesign: create a hyperlink to a PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, interaction

I am formatting a research paper in InDesign, and I'm working on making it interactive. I'm trying to add a hyperlink to this PDF:

> http://in.gov/isda/files/Promoting_the_Good_Works_of_Indiana_Agriculture_Release.pdf

Every time I try to create a hyperlink to its url, the hyperlinks panel lists its status as "URL is Unavailable."

So, is it possible to create a hyperlink in InDesign to a PDF? If so, is there a different method that I need to use? Thanks

Update: Here's a picture showing the hyperlinks panel and the edit hyperlink panels pulled up.

[image: Hyperlinks Panel]

Comment: Have you checked for mistakes in the URL such as double *http://* (since the URL field in the hyperlink panel contains that by default)? Can you post a screenshot of the hyperlink panel with your link visible?

Answer (score 1):

If you export to Interactive PDF, explicit URLs will be hyperlinked. Since it's a reference list with explicit URL, maybe you want to try that.

If you want to create hyperlinks using the links panel, check that *_destination_* field is "URL" but not "Shared destination".

This might help: http://indesignsecrets.com/understanding-indesigns-hyperlink-formatting.php

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you can do:

- paste your url as normal text and forget about it (nothing else needed really)
- when exporting to PDF, check the boxes in red below. this will **auto-detect** there is a url in your text and **automatically** place a link on it
- please note this will *not* add any special formatting to your link. it will look the same as the text in the paragraph. some extra formatting will be needed if you want this link to look different

[image: indesign pdf export settings]